# Queues and Stacks

Tags: java

I'm having trouble writing a program that determines whether a string is a palindrome that gets an input string from the user while skipping whitespace characters and punctuation, and ignoring differences in case, storing each character in both a stack and a queue. I already have it determining if it's a palindrome. The part i'm having trouble in is sorting it in the queue and stack. The following is what I have right now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pali
{

    static int length;
    static String st;
    static ListStack stack = new ListStack();
    static ListQueue lq = new ListQueue();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


  public static void main (String[] args)
 {
     text();
        String s = null;
     createStack(s);
        String q = null;
     createQueue(q);
  }


    public static void text()
    {

  String st, _n = "y";
  int left, right;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  while (_n.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
  {
     System.out.println ("Enter a potential palindrome:");
     st = scan.nextLine();



     left = 0;
     right = st.length() - 1;

     while (st.charAt(left) == st.charAt(right) && left < right)
     {
        left++;
        right--;
     }

     System.out.println();

     if (left < right)
        System.out.println ("That string is NOT a palindrome.");
     else
        System.out.println ("That string IS a palindrome.");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print ("Test another palindrome (y/n)? ");
     _n = scan.nextLine();
    }

    }
    public static void createStack(String s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(s.charAt(i));

    }

    }
    public static void createQueue(String q)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); i++)
        {
            lq.enqueue(q.charAt(i));
        }
     }

    public static void palindrome(ListQueue l, ListStack m)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < m.size();i++)
       {


       }



   }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pali
{
    
    static int length;
    static String st;
    static ListStack stack = new ListStack();
    static ListQueue lq = new ListQueue();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
  public static void main (String[] args)
 {
     text();
        String s = null;
     createStack(s);
        String q = null;
     createQueue(q);
  }

Comment: "a program that determines whether a string is a palindrome" sounds like [homework] to me. Please tag as such if that is so.

Comment: public static void text()
    {
            
  String st, _n = "y";
  int left, right;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  while (_n.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
  {
     System.out.println ("Enter a potential palindrome:");
     st = scan.nextLine();



     left = 0;
     right = st.length() - 1;

Comment: while (st.charAt(left) == st.charAt(right) && left < right)
     {
        left++;
        right--;
     }

     System.out.println();

     if (left < right)
        System.out.println ("That string is NOT a palindrome.");
     else
        System.out.println ("That string IS a palindrome.");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print ("Test another palindrome (y/n)? ");
     _n = scan.nextLine();
    }
        
    }

Comment: user1006161 Post your code in your original question. Not in the comments section.

Comment: You aren't looping through the stack or queue to see where to place the new string, realizing you will need to pop/dequeue to remove and then put those back in place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a stack and a queue? Or are you only doing it because someone suggested it to you?
In your current code you're not actually using the stack or queue at all, you just making them and filling them with null strings.

Your original code bit manipulating the string isn't so bad, but try to add in a step that formats your string, so you get rid of case, get rid of other anything not a letter, get rid of white space's etc etc. Get that step working, then try and check if it's a palindrome.

And no I'm not going to tell you how to do it, because I recently had to do that same thing and I know how easy it is to find...